# How to properly use the light sensor values in android?

Tags: java, android, android-sensors

i'm trying to develop and android app. In particular my app needs to do the following:

1 - I have to read the values of the light sensor of the mobile phone;

2 - If the value read is greater than 50.0 lux I have to save 1, otherwise 0;

3 - The reading of the values has to have a baudrate and a duration defined by the user;

4 - Then, there are some operation with these datas: they have to be split into packets of 8-bit with an additional start-bit, end-bit and one parity bit;

5 - Finally, I have to save all the packets in a .txt file

Regarding to point 1 and 2 I'm okay, I have used the Sensor and SensorManager classes.

For point 3 I'm also okay, becuase I have used EditText in the UI for the baudrate and the duration.

Now I'm struggling with the last two points. In particular, I don't know how to use the values read to perform the operations mentioned in point 4, and i can't understand how to integrate all these components together.

Comment: Hi there, Are you looking for someone who can do your task ? Because here you first try and post any possible errors and ask for help~